# NHibernate - SafeHandle Cannot be Null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to connect to an Oracle database. Everything was fine until I suddenly started to get the strange `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: SafeHandle cannot be null.` error. I am not sure what I have changed to get this error and I do not know what exactly it means. Google does not give results too. Below is the full stack trace. Any ideas ?

Error happens when `BuildSessionFactory` is called:

```
 var x = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
            .ConnectionString(connectionString))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
        .BuildConfiguration();

    return x.BuildSessionFactory();
```

> at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle
>   pHandle, Boolean& success)    at
>   System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.OCIAttrSet(OciHandle trgthndlp,
>   HTYPE trghndltyp, Byte[] attributep, UInt32 size, ATTR attrtype,
>   OciHandle errhp)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.TracedNativeMethods.OCIAttrSet(OciHandle
>   trgthndlp, Byte[] attributep, UInt32 size, ATTR attrtype, OciHandle
>   errhp)    at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle.SetAttribute(ATTR
>   attribute, String value, OciErrorHandle errorHandle)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String
>   userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
>   at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString
>   connectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) 
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()    at
>   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()    at
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
>   at
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect
>   dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)    at
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory
>   sessionFactory)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping
>   mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)    at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()    at
>   Models.SessionFactory.CreateOracleConnection(String connectionString)
>   in c:\Users\CMENGU\Projects\TNT\Models\SessionManager.cs:line 21    at
>   TNT.SessionManager.InitOracleFactory() in
>   c:\Users\CMENGU\Projects\TNT\TNT\SessionManager.cs:line 29    at
>   TNT.Program.Main() in c:\Users\CMENGU\Projects\TNT\TNT\Program.cs:line
>   30    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Both the SafeHandle and other parts of the error point to an issue with the connnection. Make sure the Db is Ok, that nobody changed a setting or a schema etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Nothing works. DB is OK. I can connect with Toad and everyone else in my team can run the code successfully. Not sure what is going on

Comment: That all points to a problem in your configuration, not in your code. I'm no Oracle expert but try to find out what has changed. Something has. Driver DLLs, listener configs, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was the visual studio 2015 preview that was somehow messing up something related to oracle libraries which led to this error. I had to reformat my pc couple of times until I understood whats going on.